# Apache POI creating corrupt XLSX files

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to create a simple Excel file in XLSX format.
I can create the old XLS files but when I try to create the other format, the file is always corrupt.

I'm using Apache POI 4.1.1.

This is my simple code:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
        
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("Hellooooo");
        
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Public/invoice_file/Test.xlsx");
        
try {
            
    wb.write(fo);
    fo.flush();
    fo.close(); 
    wb.close();
            
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this is the error message: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6qcF.png)

Comment: Changing the extension of the file to `.xlsx` doesn't turn the file into XLSX type.

Comment: This basically works on my machine, but I moved the declaration of the `FileOutputStream` into the scope of the `try` (could be the reason) and used a different path notation (which is, admittedly, unlikely to have caused a corrupted file).

Comment: can you try to declare variables as XSSFWorkbook, XSSFSheet, XSSFRow, ...etc?

Comment: @JLazar0 Yes, I can. But this can't solve my problem.

Comment: @deHaar what poi version number are you using?

Comment: I used `4.0.1` first, then switched to the version you used. Both of them have produced a valid file that I could open in Excel. Even the cell `"A1"` contained the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory

//Parameter indicates whether you want to create an XSSF formatted file or not
WorkbookFactory.create(true);  //true creates XSSF formatted file
```

will return you an instance of

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
```

Then you can write to the file using

```
Workbook.write(OutputStream)
```

Solution:

```
try (Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(true)) {
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Hellooooo");
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/Test.xlsx")) {
        wb.write(fos);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I always get the same error...

Comment: Can you please put here the exact error?
Or is it the same that you have posted earlier in your question?

I tried my above solution, and the file opened up fine.

Comment: the same problem.

Comment: That is strange.  I could open it fine.  Which JDK version are you using?  I don't think that should affect though, but I used JDK 14.

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8.